# How to sort data in repository into alphabetical order using .stream()

Tags: java, repository, java-stream

I am trying to create a method that sorts and outputs data I have stored in a repository into alphabetical order using .stream(). Currently I have a method that sorts the data by CityID in numeric order which I will add below. Is there a way to adapt it to sort the same data but by CityName in Alphabetical order?

CityID Method -

```
private void listCityDataInCityIdOrder() {
    System.out.format("\033[31m%s\033[0m%n", "City Id Order");
    System.out.format("\033[31m%s\033[0m%n", "=============");
    repository.getItems()
            .stream()
            .sorted()
            .map(c -> c.toString())
            .forEach(str -> System.out.print(str));
}
```

Data Set -

```
1,"Cartagena","Spain",3
"2015",0.2,33,26,6,"S"
"2016",0.0,33,24,8,"SSW"
"2017",0.0,32,25,6,"E"
2,"Glasgow","Scotland",3
"2015",0.0,19,8,3,"SE"
"2016",0.1,21,11,6,"SE"
"2017",2.1,19,11,9,"SW"
```

City Model Class -

```
package model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 *
 * @author mga
 */
public class City implements Comparable<City>{
    private final int id;
    private String cityName;
    private String country;
    private List<YearData> yearDataCollection;

    private static int lastIdAllocated = 0;

    static final char EOLN='\n';
    static final String QUOTE="\"";

    public City() {
        this.id = ++lastIdAllocated;
        this.cityName = "TBC";
        this.country = "TBC";
        this.yearDataCollection = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public City(String cityName, String country) {
        this.id = ++lastIdAllocated;
        this.cityName = cityName;
        this.country = country;
        this.yearDataCollection = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public City(String cityName, String country, List<YearData> yearDataCollection) {
        this.id = ++lastIdAllocated;
        this.cityName = cityName;
        this.country = country;
        this.yearDataCollection = yearDataCollection;
    }

    public City(int id, String cityName, String country, List<YearData> yearDataCollection) {
        this.id = id;
        this.cityName = cityName;
        this.country = country;
        this.yearDataCollection = yearDataCollection;
        if (id > City.lastIdAllocated)
            City.lastIdAllocated = id;
    }


    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // Methods required:

    public String getCityName() {
        return this.cityName;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public List<YearData> getYearDataCollection() {
        return this.yearDataCollection;
    }

    public void setYearDataCollection(List<YearData> yearDataCollection) {
        this.yearDataCollection = yearDataCollection;
    }

    public void addYearData(YearData yearData) {
        this.yearDataCollection.add(yearData);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\nCity Id: " + id + " - City Name: " + cityName +
                " - Country: " + country + "\nData: " + yearDataCollection + "\n";
    }


    public String toString(char delimiter) {
        final char EOLN='\n';
        final String QUOTE="\"";
        String str = Integer.toString(this.id) + delimiter +
                QUOTE + this.cityName + QUOTE + delimiter +
                QUOTE + this.country + QUOTE + delimiter +
                Integer.toString(yearDataCollection.size()) + EOLN;
        for (YearData yearData : yearDataCollection) {
            str += yearData.toString();
        }
        return str;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (this == object) return true;
        if (!(object instanceof City)) return false;
        if (!super.equals(object)) return false;
        City city = (City) object;
        return getId() == city.getId() &&
                java.util.Objects.equals(getCityName(), city.getCityName()) &&
                java.util.Objects.equals(getCountry(), city.getCountry()) &&
                java.util.Objects.equals(getYearDataCollection(), city.getYearDataCollection());
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), getId(), getCityName(), getCountry(), getYearDataCollection());
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(City compareCity) {

        int cityId =
                ((City) compareCity).getId();

        //ascending order
        return this.id - cityId;

        //descending order
        //return cityId - this.id;
    }


    public static Comparator<City> CityComparator = new Comparator<City>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(City city1, City city2) {

            String cityName1 = city1.getCityName();
            String cityName2 = city2.getCityName();

            //ascending order
            //return cityName1.compareTo(cityName2);

            //descending order
            return cityName2.compareTo(cityName1);
        }
   };

}
```

Comment: The `.sorted(...)` method has an overload that takes a Comparator as per the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html). Please check the API first when asking questions where the API can provide useful information.

Comment: You don't need to call `toString()` to print.

Comment: Your `equals` and `hashCode` implementations make no sense. When you call their `super` implementations in a class directly extending `java.lang.Object`, the object will be only equal to itself. That's not different to not having your own implementation of `equals` and `hashCode`  at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sure, change your `sorted` to:

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(City::getCityName))
```

or using lambda:

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(c -> c.getCityName()))
```

Comment: `T` should be substituted with whatever type `repository.getItems()` returns e.g. if it returns `Stream<City>` for example then you'd have `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(City::cityName))` where the `cityName` is a placeholder for whatever attribute in your model stores the city name, if you don't get what I am saying then post your model class along with the attributes it has.

Comment: I've implemented as above and the weather data now outputs correctly, my only problem is that it shows the wrong city for each set of data i.e. instead of showing 'Cartagena' it shows 'Glasgow'. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: @JosephBurke I believe because the comparator here does not do the same thing as your `CityComparator`, it needs to reverse as well. You can check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53584972/1746118) on how to do that.

Comment: @nullpointer well I was told from the description "Is there a way to adapt it to sort the same data but by CityName in **Alphabetical** order?" not in descending order. but yes if they want descending then `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(City::getCityName).reversed())`

Comment: @nullpointer  Just to clarify, i want the data to sort and display by city in alphabetical order for example if I SWAP the CityID's around, when i run this method it should still show Cartagena's data first with that city and then Glasgow's data.

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify your Comparator

```
public static Comparator<City> CityComparator = new Comparator<City>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(City city1, City city2) {

        String cityName1 = city1.getCityName();
        String cityName2 = city2.getCityName();

        //ascending order
        //return cityName1.compareTo(cityName2);

        //descending order
        return cityName2.compareTo(cityName1);
    }
};
```

to just this :

```
Comparator<City> cityComparatorSimplified = Comparator
        .comparing(City::getCityName).reversed(); // reverse for descending order
```

and then use it further while sorting as

```
repository.getItems().stream()
            .sorted(cityComparatorSimplified)
            .map(Object::toString)
            .forEach(System.out::print);
```